# dynamic space partitioning tree data structures?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, theory, computational-geometry

I have an application where I need to do nearest neighbor, rectangle/polygon overlap and other basic computational geometry operations against dynamically changing data (all 2d.)  I understand the basic data structures in the static case (quadtrees, 2-dimensional Kd-trees, R-trees, BSP, etc.) but I want to understand the state of the art in the dynamic case.  The difficulty seems to be knowning when/how to balance on insertion and deletion.  For example, is there a dynamic data structure that answers k-nearest neighbors against n points in O(log n + k), where insertion and deletion take O(log n) (amortized, maybe)?  Is there a standard reference that summarizes what's known about this problem?

Comment: Did you find any suitable data structure?
I'd be happy to hear your progress on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I haven't done too much with dynamic trees myself (mostly static). But I believe the Bkd-tree paper (early 2000s?) is good source to start. I believe it has been referenced many times since then. You can use sources like acm/citeseer to track newer papers that reference it. Side note: i think there is public code available for Bkds so you can play with it without investing too much time - see if it works for you.

Bkd-Tree: A Dynamic Scalable kd-Tree
Octavian Procopiuc, Pankaj K. Agarwal, Lars Arge, and Jeffrey Scott Vitter

Comment: Thanks!  I actually looked briefly at that paper, but it didn't dig deeper because it is addressing searching in external (on disk) spacial databases.  "In this paper, we present the ﬁrst theoretically and practically eﬃcient dynamic adaptation of the kd-tree to external memory."  I'll take another look.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a monster curve (space filling curve). A fast algorithm is to simply interleave the x and y coordinate. It also possible for 3 dimensions.

Comment: I don't understand your first suggestion.  Can you elaborate or give a reference?  Interleaving x and y is the standard kd-tree construction.  That doesn't explain how to keep the tree balanced.

Comment: Sure but it's a tree. I mean interleave the coordinate. Anyway look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx